# How can I recognize text with little math symbols by tesseract OCR?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, image-recognition

My text with some not such complex math symbols as below.

[image]

[image]

Tesseract OCR default cannot recognize such math symbols (+-, angle). How can I recognize such math symbols by tesseract ?

Answer (score 2):

just use the following statement:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img), config='-l eng + equ')
```

Also make sure pytesseract is trained with equations.

tifi